# Python tkinter - Searching for key word that is not a sub string

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import keyword
from tkinter import END

def highlight(text):
    keywords = keyword.kwlist
    for kw in keywords:
        text.tag_remove(kw, 1.0, END)
        first = 1.0

        while True:
            first = text.search(
                kw, first,
                nocase=False,
                stopindex=END
            )

            if first is None or first == "":
                break
            
            first_splitted = first.split(".")
            if len(first_splitted) == 1:
                break

            last = f"{first_splitted[0]}.{int(first_splitted[1]) + len(kw)}"

            character_position_before_first = f"{first_splitted[0]}.{int(first_splitted[1]) - 1}"
            character_before_first = text.get(character_position_before_first)

            last_splitted = last.split(".")

            character_position_after_last = f"{last_splitted[0]}.{int(last_splitted[1])}"
            character_after_last = text.get(character_position_after_last)

            if not character_before_first.isspace() and not character_after_last.isspace():   
                break

            text.tag_add(kw, first, last)
            first = last
            
        text.tag_config(
            kw,
            foreground="#aa71eb"
        )
```

Given the following code, I'm trying to highlight key words in a text. The issue is that sub strings are being marked.

**Example:**
`hello this is a test open works too lmao lol lol lol`
Would mark `is` from `this` and `is`

I only want it to mark the second `is` as the first `is` is a sub string of `this`

I have no clue why the code above is not working. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never actually used this capability, but you can add a `regexp=True` parameter to the `.search()` call, which will allow you to specify constraints such as word boundaries.  Adding `\m` before, and `\M` after your search keyword will match only whole words.

Comment: @jasonharper
```py
first = text.search(f"\m{kw}\M", first, nocase=False, stopindex=END, regexp=True)``` like this?

Comment: You want to add an `r` in front of the pattern (so that Python doesn't try to interpret the backslashes itself), but that's the general idea.